# Where is error in my List comprehension code?

Tags: python-3.x

I know this may sound a basic question , but i was recently reading the list comprehension. Then i tried the following code, but it is giving me an error (Invalid Syntax).

```
 r=0   
 # x=[r=r+1  for c in l1 if l1.count(c) == 1] --> **Invalid syntax**
 for c in l1 : # **But this works in loop**
   if l1.count(c)==1 :
      r+=1
print(r)
```

Sp where is the problem ??

Comment: what would be the return value of `r=r+1`, you are building a list of this value...

Comment: actually i was trying to count the number of single appeared chars in a list , r is a counter which will count the single appeared chars

Comment: You could just do len(set(l1)). Sets are nice https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: No, you can't do `len(set(l1))` because he wants only unique items.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of chars that appear once. Since they appear once, they won't be repeated in your list.

Alternatively, if you want a different length, use set `{}` instead (no repetition)

```
unique_chars = [ c for c in l1 if l1.count(c)==1 ]
print(len(unique_chars))
```

Answer (score 0):

`[r=r+1  for c in l1 if l1.count(c) == 1]` is an invalid syntax since you cannot have assignment operators in a list comprehension.

If you want to use list comprehensions, count 1 if a element occurs 1, else count 0, and sum up the counts

```
l1 = ['a','b','c','c','d','e']

#Count 1 for an element occuring once, otherwise count 0, and sum up the counts
r = sum([1 if l1.count(c) == 1 else 0 for c in l1])
print(r)
```

The output will be `4`

Another way to do it is to count the frequency of character using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)  and count how many values are 1

```
from collections import Counter
l1 = ['a','b','c','c','d','e']

#Take a counter
c = Counter(l1)

#Count 1 for an element occuring once, otherwise count 0, and sum up the counts
r = sum([1 if v == 1 else 0 for v in c.values()])
print(r)
```

The output will be `4`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just wanted this to happen.

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,6,8]
print(len([x for x in l1 if l1.count(x)==1]))
```

output-> `5` that is (`1,3,4,5,7`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have assignments inside a list comprehension. If I understood, you are trying to count the unique items in the list, so you can do it in a very simple way:

```
r = len([x for x in l1 if l1.count(x) == 1])
print(r)
```